# Is it possible to make colorbox open within a form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm working with an old system and I'm trying to upgrade from jQuery 1.7.4 to 3.2.1 and as a result I appear to need to upgrade colorbox from 1.4.0 to 1.6.4. However I'm running into an issue to do with where the popup gets loaded in the DOM.

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox_v1_6_4\colorbox.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="colorbox_v1_6_4\jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myform">           
    <button id='openPopupButton'>Open Popup</button>
    <div style="display: none">
        <div class="myPopupBox">                                    
            <button id="mySubmitButton" type="submit">Submit the form</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("#openPopupButton").click(function (e) {
          // Hook up login as user confirmation dialog
          jQuery.colorbox({ href: jQuery(this).parent().find('.myPopupBox'), inline: true });
          e.preventDefault();
      });

      jQuery('#myform').submit(function(e) {
        alert('It Worked!');
        e.preventDefault();
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

When the `#openPopupButton` button is pressed it should show the form. When the `#mySubmitButton` button is pressed the form should be submitted which should show an alert with the words 'It Worked!'.

The original system (which was using colorbox 1.4.0) works fine, however when I switch to colorbox 1.6.4 it stops working. This appears to be because the new version of colorbox creates the popup in the DOM outside the `<form>` tag where as the old version created it inside.

Is there anyway to get colorbox to create the form inside the `<form>` tag and thus have the submit button submit the form?

Comment: check for an option in plugin docs regarding where it gets appended. Some modal/dialog plugins have such a feature

Comment: @charlietfl that was exactly what I was hoping someone could point me at. I've taken a look at the docs http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and can't seem to see an option that does that.